# How Apache Limit POST Tags accept only Server Request?

Tags: php, apache, php-7, windows-server-2012-r2, apache2.4

I am trying to harden an *Apache 2.4* Web server running 2 wordpress sites with separate vhost settings. Deployed on Windows 2012 r2. I was hacked a few weeks ago and the server was completely lost. On the new server they are still trying to hack the site with post request injections/code executions. I'm having trouble trying to block all `POST` request that are not sent by the server on submission.

Things I have tried include

- `<Location>`, `<Directory>`, `<Limit>` tags with their attributes like `GET`,`PUT`, `POST PUT DELETE` trying varied combos with various `Require` statements ie. `local`, `ip`, `host`, and `order allow, deny` patterns. `Allow all from`
- `<Directory "/">`, `<Location >`,`<LimitExcept >` Tags including attributes such as `GET`,`POST` and combos.
- Various `<if >` statements
- `AllowMethod` Statements
- Whitelisting Directories in the `.htacess`

Placing attempts in different file context. Such as `httpd.conf`, `Vhost.conf`, `.htaccess`. Any file I found referenced in Apache docs related to the directive context. Even placed it where it should not work for giggles. Nothing, I read in the docs or on stack overflow seemed to work.

All auth Modules loaded like mod_auth, mod_host etc. Just assume Modules are fine.

What I would like to achieve is to `deny` or `<Limit POST>` request. Strictly allowing them in a dynamic `<Directory "/.*"> or` ` being responded to only when the server submits the Request using the server IP. Therefore the IP:port of the request should be the "remote address" because the apache local service sends the request method via PHP. I believe this to be correct logic.

The last thing I had time to try before leaving work, is the below code attempting a dynamic `<Directory "/.*"> tag I do not want to dig through Wordpress for every form and create a tag for each directory.

Thank you for the help, please include a code example with your answer.

```
<Directory "/.*">
<if "%{REQUEST_METHOD} == 'POST'">
<Limit POST PUT DELETE>
Require req, http %{REMOTE_ADDR} == 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xx'
</Limit>
</if>
</Directory>
```

Now I tried

```
<Directory "/"> 
<if "($_SERVER['%{REMOTE_ADDR}'] == 'xx.xx.xx.xx'">
<Limit POST>
allow from all
</Limit>
</if>
</Directory>
```

```
<Directory "/"> 
<if "($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'xx.xx.xx.xx'">
<Limit POST>
allow from all
</Limit>
</if>
</Directory>
```

Today I tried the following
it led to Wordpress now having a 500 Instead of a 403
I tried these in the htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
AllowMethod POST
<LimitExcept GET>
   Require ip "xx.xx.xx.xx"
</LimitExcept GET>
} 
</IfModule>
```

```
<Directory "/.*">
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
AllowMethod POST
<LimitExcept GET>
   Require ip "xx.xx.xx.xx"
</LimitExcept GET>
} 
</IfModule>
```

```
<Directory "/">
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
RewriteCond req(-R == %{REMOTE_ADDR})
AllowMethod GET POST
order allow,deny
allow from all
<LimitExcept GET>
   Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx
</LimitExcept>
} 
</IfModule>
</Directory>
```

```
<Directory "/">
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
RewriteCond req(-R == %{REMOTE_ADDR})
#AllowMethod GET POST
AllowOverride All
order allow,deny
allow from all
<LimitExcept GET>
  # Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx
deny from all
</LimitExcept>
} 
</IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Stick to relevant solutions in regard to the config posted Please.

Comment: WordPress on public internet == pain. Put a GET only proxy on the internet that reverse feeds from an admin wp install in VPC. Allow POST, PUT etc on front only for explicitly allowed public facing operations (eg comments).  Any attempt to harden a full wordpress install on the public inet nkw will likely be invalidated and exploited in the near future with new wp bugs.

Comment: We do not have comments, the only data the user needs to submit is Contact us and Signing up for becoming a dealer for the main site. The second site they need to login and submit product info for warranties. As well as more crud operations.  Ultimately I agree, I had WP I prefer Javascript web apps  like MERN.

Answer (score 1):

write a code like this

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
     // Your code here
}
```

Comment: To me that looks more like a js solution. So I  wrap the arguments with `( )`  even inside the `v-host.conf` file?

Comment: you can use like this
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'Your server ip') {
     // Your code here
}

Comment: I tried `<if "($_SERVER['%{REMOTE_ADDR}'] == 'xx.xx.xx.xx'">` it didn't work with our with out `${}` wrapping the `REMOTE_ADDR`